# How to properly set up the mapbox GL using Android App?

Tags: android, reactjs, react-native, mapbox

I have module where I need to integrate the mapbox GL to my react native application project. the installation of mapbox gl is successfully and this happen when I run the android it gives me an error.

> FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':app:mergeDexDebug'.

> A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.Workers$ActionFacade
> com.android.builder.dexing.DexArchiveMergerException: Error while merging dex archives:
> The number of method references in a .dex file cannot exceed 64K.
> Learn how to resolve this issue at https://developer.android.com/tools/building/multidex.html

- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 43s

error Failed to install the app. Make sure you have the Android development environment set up: https://reactnative.dev/docs/environment-setup. Run CLI with --verbose flag for more details.
Error: Command failed: gradlew.bat app:installDebug -PreactNativeDevServerPort=8081
Note: C:\mobile_project\DriverApp\android\app\src\debug\java\com\driverapp\ReactNativeFlipper.java uses or overrides a deprecated API.

I already do testing where the error happens is inside the mapbox GL, when I remove the dependencies of mapbox in the package.json my project is running and no error found.

The question here is why this error happens? did someone experience or is there any thread regarding on this?

**My React Native Version:**

- react-native-cli: 2.0.1
- react-native: 0.63.4

**Mapbox GL Requirements:**

**Installation**

Prerequisite On Android we support from version 6 (API 23) upwards

**Dependencies**

- Node
- NPM
- React Native (0.60+)

"@react-native-mapbox-gl/maps": "^8.1.0-rc10",

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found this answer and it worked for me in a React Native app:

At Path android/app/build.gradle

```
defaultConfig {
    multiDexEnabled true //Add this line
}
```

https://github.com/react-native-webview/react-native-webview/issues/1344#issuecomment-650544648